# How to get value of a variable in a long delimited string

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

In a db table I have a string, such as...

```
Var1=0;CosType=1;DefaultType=US_Pass;DateYear=1;DateRange=1;ReportFormat=0
```

I want to create a VB.NET function that has 1 input var, the string (above) and the "token" to get the value for. (The return value is the value of the token.) For example, if I call it (LongString is the string above)....

```
txtValue.text = MyFunction(LongString,"DefaultType")
```

So, "US_Pass" would be returned.

What is the most efficient way to code MyFunction?

I've tried something like this...

```
return LongString.Substring(LongString.IndexOf(input_token) + 12)
```

I feel I'm close, but so far away.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works as long as you know the key exists in your string:

```
public string MyFunction(string longString, string key)
{
    return
        longString
            .Split(';')
            .Select(x => x.Split('='))
            .ToDictionary(x => x[0], x => x[1])[key];
}
```

With this code:

```
string longString = "Var1=0;CosType=1;DefaultType=US_Pass;DateYear=1;DateRange=1;ReportFormat=0";
Console.WriteLine(MyFunction(longString, "DefaultType"));
```

I get:

```
US_Pass
```

As VB.NET:

```
Public Function MyFunction(longString As String, key As String) As String
    Return longString.Split(";"c).Select(Function(x) x.Split("="c)).ToDictionary(Function(x) x(0), Function(x) x(1))(key)
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks! I get an error that "Select is not a member of system.array". Any ideas? It doesn't like "Select" I think.

Comment: Add in `Imports System.Linq` at the top of your code.

Answer (score 1):

1. Split the string into parts at the semi-colons.

   ```
   Dim parts As String() = LongString.Split(";")
   ```
2. Loop over the parts in a `ForEach` loop.
3. Find the part that `StartsWith` the the token value.
4. Find the equal sign (`IndexOf`) and take everything to the right of it (`Substring`).

That should give you enough to figure it out.

Comment: Will this work for the last token which doesn't have a semicolon?

Comment: Try it and find out. This site isn't for us to completely do your assignment for you.

Comment: Thanks I got it working. The down vote wasn't cool though. It was a legit question and it did show "research effort".

Answer (score 1):

It's probably not a great idea to store data like this in your database. Hopefully you won't need to query these attributes from SQL.

In your case I would create a class to encapsulate the attributes. You pass in the string as a constructor parameter and let the class manage it.

Here's an example in C# that shouldn't be too hard to convert to VB:

```
public class AttributeCollection
{
    private readonly Dictionary<string, string> _attrs;

    public AttributeCollection(string values)
    {
        _attrs = (from v in values.Split(new[] {';'})
            select v.Split(new[] {'='})).ToDictionary(i => i[0], i => i[1]);
    }

    public string this[string name]
    {
        get { return _attrs[name]; }
        set { _attrs[name] = value; }
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Join(";", (from a in _attrs select a.Key + "=" + a.Value).ToArray());
    }
}
```